# Xcode 4 Core Data attribute options

Tags: core-data, attributes, xcode4

In Xcode 3, project.xcdatamodel had three panes (Entities, Properties, and Detail) along the top with a graphical thing for looking at your data model (Diagram view). If I wanted to, for example, make my `isOverdue` attribute `Transient`, I'd just go up to whichever one of those panels has that option (I never did Core Data before Xcode 4) and be done with it. Xcode 4 is a pretty dramatic change from Xcode 3, and I can't find the button or menu to do the same thing. The Version Editor lets you look at the source code, but it's locked for editing, and I can't imagine that as being the only option.

Google doesn't have anything relevant with any searches I can come up with, and right-clicking on everything hasn't helped at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at the three buttons at the top-right of the toolbar. The right-most (that looks like a shaded right-hand pane) reveals the Utility pane. Make sure the data model is selected in the project navigator. From the Utility pane's toolbar, choose the database-looking icon (the right-most one). All the options are found there.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. I opened that pane before, but never clicked the button at the top. Thanks.

Comment: Most of Xcode 4's learning curve is finding where things got to (and discovering things that are missing).